# how do i fix this javascript prompt=userInput from array to alert problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, alert, prompt

Once I run this code i should be getting userInput which is a number between 0-3 and the name of the pizza in alert box. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var menu = [
  "0 = Calzone",
  "1 = Ost & Skinke",
  "2 = Margarita",
  "3 = BBQ Grill"
];

var userPostnummer = prompt("skriv inn postnummer")

if (userPostnummer >= 1000 && userPostnummer <= 1999) {
  alert("gratulerer du får et gratis pizza")
  var userInput = prompt("hvilket meny ønsker du å bestille?" + menu) + alert("pizza " + userInput + " er på vei til postnummer " + userPostnummer)

} else {
  alert("beklager, du er ikke i området hvor vi tilbyr gratis pizza")
};
```

Comment: `var userInput  = prompt(...) + alert(...)` Why is the alert being added to the prompt?

Comment: `var userInput = prompt("hvilket meny ønsker du å bestille?" + menu); 
      if (userInput) alert("pizza " + userInput + ".....`

Comment: Jeg vil helst ha en pølse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you receive `undefined` is because you're trying to use `userInput` before it's finally declared. You try to use it in an `alert` in the same operation in the declaration.

You need to separate the alert to be executed after `userInput` has got its value, like below.

If you also want to refer to the "pizza value" in the `menu` array, you need to replace `userInput` with `menu[userInput]`

```js
var menu = [
  "0 = Calzone",
  "1 = Ost & Skinke",
  "2 = Margarita",
  "3 = BBQ Grill"
];

var userPostnummer = prompt("skriv inn postnummer")

if (userPostnummer >= 1000 && userPostnummer <= 1999) {
  alert("gratulerer du får et gratis pizza")
  var userInput = prompt("hvilket meny ønsker du å bestille?" + menu); 
  // Alert is now on its own row.
  // userInput is also replaced with menu[userInput]
  if (userInput < menu.length)
    alert("pizza " + menu[userInput] + " er på vei til postnummer " + userPostnummer)

} else {
  alert("beklager, du er ikke i området hvor vi tilbyr gratis pizza")
};
```

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._